# CakePHP 3 - Form data format for patchEntities()

Tags: forms, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

My question is pretty straightforward: **How should form data look like (e.i. what should the name keys look like) to patch multiple entities using `patchEntities()`?**

I have read
**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting Multiple Records](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records)**, but it does not explicitly mention how to use it.

This structure works for `newEntities()`:

```
        $data = [
            '0' => ['field1' => '...', /* ... */],
            '1' => ['field1' => '...', /* ... */],
            '2' => ['field1' => '...', /* ... */]
        ];
```

With a form like:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('0.field1', /* ... */) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('1.field1', /* ... */) ?>
...
```

However, the same structure but with `'id.field1'` does not make any changes to entities in `patchEntities()`.

Comment: Not sure what you want, for this "'id.field1'", id should be the array key, so that you will have multiple sub-array and then you can convert that to Entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form data should look the same, with the exception that it should include the records primary keys, so that the marshaller can map the data on the respective records. The leading number there in your form inputs isn't a primary key (id), but just the resulting array index.

The docs could use a little update there to include `patchEntities()` too, right now there's only a short section hidden in the "*Patching HasMany and BelongsToMany*" section.

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Patching HasMany and BelongsToMany](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#patching-hasmany-and-belongstomany)**

So the form should look something like:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('0.id', /* ... */) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('0.field1', /* ... */) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('1.id', /* ... */) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('1.field1', /* ... */) ?>
<!-- ... -->
```

resulting in a dataset like:

```
$data = [
    '0' => ['id' => '...', 'field1' => '...', /* ... */],
    '1' => ['id' => '...', 'field1' => '...', /* ... */],
    // ...
];
```

which can then be patched on the given entities:

```
$original = $this->Table->find()->toArray();
$patched = $this->Table->patchEntities($original, $data);
```

Comment: Thanks @ndm, that answers my question exactly. Still a shame the model `->save()` function does not support multiple entities.